# How can I make an axios call before rendering and store a session?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-state-management

I have tried many tutorials and so far, I can display items and get a little bit around React.

The URL structure is

```
/works/2
```

The query string of 2 is stored inside of `pageID`

I then fire the ajax call and filter the database to only show that data with `.find()`

This is the `WorksPage.js` file which will list the company work portfolio items.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './index.css';

class WorksPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {itemList: []};
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        const pageID = this.props.match.params.page;
        axios.get('/api/works.json').then(function(response){
            const result = response.data.find(i => i.id === pageID);
            this.setState({ isLoaded: true, itemList: result });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    render(){
        return(

            <div className="workListing pageWrapper">
                <section className="workListing-process">
                    <div className="smcontainer center txtc">
                     {this.state.itemList}
                     App Type: {this.state.itemList.sub}

                     App cars: {this.state.itemList.cars.map((car, i) =>

                      <div key={i}>
                        {car}
                      </div>

                    )}

                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


export default WorksPage;
```

My JSON of `works.json` is

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "img": "/images/slider.jpg",
    "header": "GPS Module",
    "sub": "iOS",
    "link": "/works/0",
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}{
    "id": 1,
    "img": "/images/map-slider.jpg",
    "header": "GPS Mapping Vectors",
    "sub": "iOS",
    "link": "/works/1",
    "cars":[  ]
},{
    "id": 2,
    "img": "/images/slider.jpg",
    "header": "GPS Module",
    "sub": "Android",
    "link": "/works/2",
    "cars":[ "Ferrari", "BMW", "Land Rover" ]
}]
```

So far the `{this.state.itemList}` returns blank. The car list loop is also not working. Console.log will return the data of `result` if I do the console.log after the `this.setState`

Comment: I have once suffered something similar to this because axios' `then()` hook wont let me access the `this`. so  i worked that out by putting `let self = this` before axios call and using `self.setState()` inside `then ()` block. Also, what do you see on Network tab under your browser's dev tools panel in response to this get request ?

Comment: There were no errors anywhere. The string to integer solution worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not use componentWillMount, it's both [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) and not meant for calling APIs. Use componentDidMount instead.

I assume the problem is that `pageID` is string and `id` is number, thus nothing gets matched. Try converting `pageID` to number before comparing it.

```
const pageID = parseInt(this.props.match.params.page, 10);
```

Comment: I applied this solution also added the `this` keyword so I could refer back as @jsDevia wrote. I also used `componentDidMount`.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You use 'this' keyword in callback function, and it refers to the call back itself not the component.
and also use componentDidmount, componenwillmount is not used anymore.
see here : [componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

use this :

```
componentDidMount(){
        let that = this;
        const pageID = this.props.match.params.page;
        axios.get('/api/works.json').then(function(response){
            const result = response.data.find(i => i.id === pageID);
            that.setState({ isLoaded: true, itemList: result });
        };
    }
```